# Selecting a default value if an entry doesn't exist

Tags: mysql

I have three tables...users, user_info, and quota_levels. They look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(31) NOT NULL,
    password VARCHAR(33) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE user_info (
    userID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    firstName VARCHAR(32),
    lastName VARCHAR(32),
    phone CHAR(14),
    address VARCHAR(128),
    birthdate DATE,
    misc TEXT,
    quotaLevel VARCHAR(32),
    PRIMARY KEY (userID)
);

CREATE TABLE quota_levels (
    quotaLevel VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    quota1 INT NOT NULL,
    quota2 INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (level)
);
```

Every user will have an entry in the `users` table, but not necessarily in the `user_info` table. Each user in the `user_info` table has a `quotaLevel` corresponding to the `quotaLevel` column in the `quota_levels` table. Possible values for `quotaLevel` are BRONZE, SILVER, GOLD, and PLATINUM.

I could go into a long explanation of why it is set up this way, but it would be quicker to just say that this structure cannot be changed.

If the user exists, I want to get the `quota1` value of their `quotaLevel`. If the user doesn't exist, the `quota1` value for BRONZE should be returned.

I want to do this with **ONE** query. Can it be done and how?

Comment: Any good reason for the downvote, or is someone just randomly clicking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT u.Name, 
       COALESCE(ql.quota1, (SELECT quota1 FROM quota_level WHERE quotaLevel = 'BRONZE'))
    FROM users u
        LEFT JOIN user_info ui  
            INNER JOIN quota_level ql
                ON ui.quotaLevel = ql.quotaLevel              
            ON u.id = ui.userID
```

Comment: I don't what the string 'BRONZE' back, I want the `quota1` value from `quota_levels` where the `quotaLevel` = BRONZE.

Comment: Looks like this is a good starting point for you. The whole point is not necessarily to give you the answer but the tools for you to answer it.

Comment: @Travesty3: OK, then hard code that value instead of the word 'BRONZE'.

Comment: The point is that I don't want a hard-coded value there. At any point, the quota levels could change, and `quota1` for BRONZE could go from 20 to 25. I want to make this change in one place (the `quota_levels` table) and not have to change any queries. Subqueries are OK, as long as it's all in one call. If it can't be done, then I will have to use two queries, but I was trying to avoid that. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @Travesty3: I spelled out the subquery for you in the answer now.

Comment: @CarlT: This is a question and answer site. Not a question and "steer you in the right direction" site. Of course, I welcome anything that does steer me in the right direction as well, but the point is to present a possible solution to my problem (which is what this answer attempted to do, and I appreciate it, but thus far it does not solve my problem).

Comment: @JoeStefanelli: Thanks, that was what I was missing.